# reshape numpy 3D array to 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very big array with the shape = (32, 3, 1e6)
I need to reshape it to this shape = (3, 32e6)

On a snippet, how to go from this::

```
>>> m3_3_5
array([[[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
        [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
        [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
        [2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]])
```

to this::

```
>>> res3_15
array([[8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
       [6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I did try various combinations with reshape with no success::

```
>>> dd.T.reshape(3, 15)
array([[8, 8, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7, 4, 8, 8, 5],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]])

>>> dd.reshape(15, 3).T.reshape(3, 15)
array([[8, 0, 8, 2, 1, 8, 0, 8, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1],
       [4, 0, 5, 1, 1, 7, 3, 5, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1],
       [1, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: You probably need a `transpose` in addition to a `reshape`.  I'm sure you'll get answers but you'll probably learn more by experimenting yourself.

Comment: Indeed.   And for what it's worth, I just found the appropriate transpose by trying a few things until one worked. :-)

Comment: Try `transpose` with an argument, something like `transpose([2,0,1])` (just a guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.transpose([1,0,2]).reshape(3,15)` will do what you want. (I am basically following comments by @hpaulj).

```
In [14]: a = np.array([[[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
        [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
        [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
        [2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]])

In [15]: a.transpose([1,0,2]).reshape(3,15)
Out[15]: 
array([[8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
       [6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: ok it clear now, I was missing the transpose *axes argument for nD array n>2

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired behavior with np.hstack

```
# g is your (3,3,5) array from above
reshaped = np.hstack(g[i,:,:] for i in range(3))  #uses a generator exp
reshaped_simpler = np.hstack(g) # this produces equivalent output to the above statmement
print reshaped # (3,30)
```

## Output

```
array([[8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
       [6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: yes, the trivial m3_3_5.reshape(3, 15) does not provide the expected result

Comment: You can simplify this to `np.hstack(g)` or `np.concatenate(g, axis=-1)`.  It iterates of the input, effectively splitting it on the 1st axis, and then reassembles it on the last axis.  This reorders the values as desired (in this case).