# multiplying large 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I would like to multyply the following matrices (using numpy) in the most efficient way.

This is the code for the matrixes:

```
a = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]])
m = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

These are the matrixes visualized better:

```
a:
[[1 5]
 [2 6]
 [3 7]
 [4 8]]

m:
[[1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1]]
```

I want to multiply a by (the first column of matrix m), like this

```
   a    m[:,0]       x0

[[1 5]   [[1]      [[1 5]
 [2 6] *  [1]   =   [2 6]    
 [3 7]    [0]       [0 0]
 [4 8]]   [0]]      [0 0]
```

And then I want to multiply a by (the second column of matrix m), like this

```
a  *  m[:,1]    =   x1
```

And then 3rd and 4th column

```
a  *  m[:,2]    =   x2
a  *  m[:,3]    =   x3
```

And finally, I want to put the resulting matrices x0,x1,x2,x3 all in one matrix.

```
X = [x0, x1, x2, x3]
```

The size X in this example is 4 x 8.

The final result in this example is:

```
X = 

[[[1 5 0 0 0 0 1 5]
  [2 6 0 0 2 6 0 0]
  [0 0 3 7 0 0 3 7]
  [0 0 4 8 4 8 4 8]]
```

I would like to know how to do this with build-in functions of numpy, and using generators, instead of using 2 for loops, if it is possible.

This is just an example. In reality the matrixes have large dimensions and it is important that the multiplications are done as fast as possible.

Thank you

Comment: Since you have example arrays, could you add the final result `X` as well?

Comment: It would be better if you visualized the result as have (4,2,4) or (4,4,2) shape.  You are doing a kind of outer product on the columns of `a` and `m`.  That's easily done with `broadcasting`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What you are suggesting would be simple for this example, but he final matrix will be used to calculate other stuff, and having the extra dimension will complicate things. Besides, I have read somewhere that for a more time-efficient code, it's better to reshape 3D numpy arrays into 2D numpy arrays, and then reshape again if needed. So, since i have to do it anyway, I want to visualize the information in this way too. Thank you.

Comment: In `numpy` reshaping is time-efficient.  The number of dimensions doesn't make much difference in calculation efficiencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I was looking for. Thank you Yatu and hpaulj.

```
X = m.T[...,None] * a
for i in range(4):
    reshaped = np.hstack(X[i,:,:])
    reshaped_simpler = np.hstack(X)
print (reshaped_simpler)
```

I got the rest of the answer from the following link:

[reshape numpy 3D array to 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470607/reshape-numpy-3d-array-to-2d)

I rearranged the for loop because I got a Warning regarding the generators going to be depricated in future versions of Numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You could transpose and expand the dimensions of `m`, to get the wanted result:

```
m.T[...,None] * a

array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [3, 7],
        [4, 8]],
        ...
```

If you want to stack the arrays horizontally to end up with a `2D` array, use `np.hstack`:

```
np.hstack(m.T[...,None] * a)

array([[1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5],
       [2, 6, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 3, 7],
       [0, 0, 4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8]])
```

Or reshaping as:

```
(a[:,None] * m[...,None]).reshape(m.shape[0], -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve it with broadcast and reshape

```
arr_out = (a[:,None] * m[...,None]).reshape(4,8)

Out[176]:
array([[1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5],
       [2, 6, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 3, 7],
       [0, 0, 4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8]])
```

Comment: This solution is the most time-efficient